# Preserve the form data when I go back to a previous page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a multi step form. When I move to the next page and decide to go back to the previous page to make changes, inputs are cleared. How can I manage this please?

Here's a recreation of the multi step form: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-spence-q3vtqw

Comment: You could use a global state like Redux or use localstorage/session storage to save the data and get them if present.

Comment: Create a state to store the form data in your component.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in 3 ways.

1. Maybe you can save all steps data in formData state. So,

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
/* 
formData = {
    step_1: {
    name: 'A'
    email: 'A.com'
    country: 'us'
    },
    step_2: {
    name: 'B',
    email: 'B.com',
    country: 'ru'
    }
}
*/

const [step, setStep] = useState(1);

const handleNext = (data) => {
    setFormData({...formData, step: data});
    setStep(step + 1);
};
```

2. You can use redux. when you input formData, please save data in reducer.
   Then you can save formData.
3. You can save formData in localStorage.

If you want detailed solution, I can help.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do this with Redux toolkit please?

Comment: It is similar to the first option. Please define formData in reducer, dispatch actions to save data in the reducer. To use the saved data, useSelector.
Then you can get the saved formData in any component, not only App. It's useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to use `localstorage`.

so,

```
localstorage.setitem(inputInfo, dataValues);

/* group all input values as a object named datavalues, and stored it on inputInfo of localstorage variable */

...

const memorizedData = localstorage.getItem(inputInfo);
if (memorizedData) dataValues = memorizedData

...

if (saveButtonClicked) localstorage.clear();
```

Good luck.